# Add reminder to calendar

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

Hi I am currently using the following code to add an event to the android's default calendar.

```
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();              
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
    intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
    intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=DAILY");
    intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
    intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
    intent.putExtra("description", "Who knows! this might work");
intent.putExtra("eventLocation", "Hope this time it works");
  intent.putExtra("hasAlarm", 1);
    startActivity(intent);
```

My question is, 
 As you can see, I have used "FREQ=DAILY", and similarly there are values such as, "FREQ=YEARLY" and "FREQ=MONTHLY".
I would like to know the other alternatives available, so that I can provide them in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh. Now I got it. I had to add this to the above code.

```
       ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
     Uri REMINDERS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(this) + "reminders");
    values = new ContentValues();
    values.put( "event_id", Long.parseLong(event.getLastPathSegment()));
    values.put( "method", 1 );
    values.put( "minutes", 5 );
    cr.insert( REMINDERS_URI, values );
```

Comment: what does this extra code did and means? please add explanation p.s i know its been asked over a year ago ! :)\